# How to send a long url with get method to server

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I have want to send a long url with GET, and I also need to add the url in the GET link, 
like this(React):

```
let urlParam = {
            apply_user: this.state.apply_user,
            order_id: this.state.order_id,
            begin_date: this.state.begin_date,
            end_date: this.state.end_date,
            status: this.state.status,
            execute_mode: this.state.execute_mode,
            page: page,
            pageSize: this.state.pageSize,
            otype:'all',
        }
        history.pushState(null, null, '?'+concatURLParams(urlParam))
```

then I can get all message from the url, like this :

```
http://cmdb.server.com/page/machine/list/?page=1&ips=172.17.10.3%20172.17.10.4%20172.17.10.9%20172.17.10.10
```

but in fact, the param is so long , there are lots of ip need to send.

And I use uwsgi to run my django project, I set buffer-size to 65536. official doc tell me the max size is 64k, but it got this, too.

```
invalid uwsgi request (current strsize: 21600). skip.
[pid: 15947|app: -1|req: -1/7]  () {0 vars in 31 bytes} [Mon Jan 14 11:18:52 2019]   => generated 0 bytes in 0 msecs ( 500) 0 headers in 0 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
```

- this is my uwsgi.ini:

```
[uwsgi]
socket=127.0.0.1:9090
chdir=/home/ops/cmdb_futu/jumpserver
module=jumpserver.wsgi
master=true
buffer-size=65536
vacuum=true
processes=8
max-requests=2000
chmod-socket=664
vacuum=true
pidfile=uwsgi.pid
```

and I set nginx `large_client_header_buffers` and `client_header_buffer_size` to 64k, too.
But I don't make it for a long time. someone know why and help me.

Comment: Did you try to chunk your request into several requests splitting 'ips' ?

Comment: yes, I have done this, but like I said, I want to add all the ip addresses in one url, then send it, and I can copy this url to another window to paste, then I can the same page and same result. if I chunk my request into several requests,  I can't share it at once.

Comment: You should probably use a POST and send the data in the request body rather than the URL.

Comment: Could It be possible to send network addresses instead of the IPs?

Comment: whatever GET or POST, I just want to add all the ip address into url, because I want  to share the url to others.

Comment: like I click the button,I will search ip: 
```127.0.0.1&127.0.0.2&127.0.0.3```
then url is
 ```http://xxyyzz.com/search/ip?ip=127.0.0.1&127.0.0.2&127.0.0.3```
people can copy this url to another window and to get same result  
**for example:**
people A search this,he wants to tell people B:"I need more information about these ip addresses".people pasted the url to a brower url bar,get same result and do next waht he need to.
But now, when I add all the IP addresses into url.(sometimes ip addresses is too many),uwsgi tell me:
```invalid uwsgi request (current strsize: 21600). skip.```